# Magento 2 How to Insert sku in product title

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, custom-options, sku

run this sql query but nothing happened::

```
 UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_text` as pt LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` as p ON p.`entity_id` = pt.`entity_id` SET pt.`value` = CONCAT(pt.`value`,' (',p.`sku`,')') WHERE pt.`attribute_id` = 75
```

Comment: why are you insert SKU in the product title? you can upend SKU last of product title using a plugin

Comment: how to Insert sku in product title programmatically any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong table join in your query. The name details for products are stored in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table. First, make sure you have the correct `attribute_id` (75) value for `name` attribute.

Use below query to achieve your requirements.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` as pt LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` as p ON p.`entity_id` = pt.`entity_id` SET pt.`value` = CONCAT(pt.`value`,' (',p.`sku`,')') WHERE pt.`attribute_id` = 75
```

Comment: yup its working thankyou so much

Comment: one more question how to Insert sku in product title programmatically any idea